# JetBrains products request permission to overwrite terminal history every time now

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I never had this issue until updating to the 2018.3 versions of my JetBrains products.
Every time I open a terminal window in WebStorm or CLion I am confronted with:

```
cp: overwrite '/home/zack/.WebStorm2018.3/config/terminal/history/history-'?
```

When I open an additional window I get:

```
cp: overwrite '/home/zack/.WebStorm2018.3/config/terminal/history/history-2'?
```

Peeking into the indicated directory reveals a number of zero-length files that is equivalent to how many terminals I have opened.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zack zack 0 Dec  6 16:14 history-
-rw-r--r-- 1 zack zack 0 Dec  6 16:18 history-2
-rw-r--r-- 1 zack zack 0 Dec  6 16:18 history-3
```

These files do remain there after I close the program, but even if I delete them, once I open up WebStorm again, the files are re-created and all the terminals that were open prompt me about over-writing the files yet again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have *cp* aliases defined in your .bashrc? Looks similar to [IDEA-202523](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202523) that is fixed in 2018.3.1